# Terminate second (parallel) process if first one is terminated

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, background-process, concurrency

Let's assume we have two shell scripts running in parallel

driver.sh:

```
./proc1.sh&
./proc2.sh&
```

how can I terminate a process if the other one exited with non-zero code? (terminate driver.sh)

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel --halt now,fail=1 ::: script1.sh script2.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some logic inside wither process to control the other upon some status change, you need to track/control them using PIDs:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
./proc1.sh &
pid_1=$!  ## PID of proc1.sh

./proc2.sh &
pid_2=$!  ## PID of proc2.sh

while ps -p ${pid_1} &>/dev/null; do :; done ##Checking for existence of proc1.sh
kill ${pid_2}  ## Killing proc2.sh when proc1.sh is not running anymore
```

Comment: Thanks but this I guess does not check for non-zero exit status of process 1 and terminates the proc2 even if proc1 exited correctly. The question is to terminate proc2 if proc1 terminated with non-zero status.